# Como validar uma expressão numérica com uma expressão regular?

Tags: php, regex, php-7

Preciso dentro da minha aplicação em PHP7 validar uma expressão numérica com uma expressão regular, o caso é que quase consegui mas esbarrei em um problema. Os zeros não significativos dentro da expressão:

Quando tenho a expressão numérica abaixo consigo validar :

```
10 + ( 10 * 10 ) - 20
```

Usando a seguinte expressão regular :

```
$cRegex  = '/^' ;
//          '|------|----|-----|---|-----|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+\(]?[\(]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+[\)]?[\)]?)?' ;
//          '|---------|----|----|-----|---|-----|----|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+[\)]?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
//          '|---------|----|----|-----|---|-----|----|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+[\)]?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
//          '|---------|----|----|-----|---|-----|----|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+[\)]?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 

$cRegex .= '$/' ;
```

Meu problema é que quando aparece a seguinte expressão numérica: `690/09`. O retorno é verdadeiro e deveria ser falso porque o correto seria `690/9`. No PHP7 o `"09"` da expressão numérica dá problema.

Por isso estou pedindo ajuda para melhorar a minha expressão regular afim de poder detectar isso.

---

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
$cRegex  = '/^' ;
//          '|---------|----|---------------|---|-----|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?([1-9]{1}[0-9]+)[.]?[0-9]+[\)]?[\)]?)' ; 
//          '|---------|----|--------------|--------|---|--------|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?([1-9]{1})([0-9]+)?[.]?([0-9]+)?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
//          '|---------|----|--------------|--------|---|--------|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?([1-9]{1})([0-9]+)?[.]?([0-9]+)?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
//          '|---------|----|--------------|--------|---|--------|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?([1-9]{1})([0-9]+)?[.]?([0-9]+)?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
//          '|---------|----|--------------|--------|---|--------|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?([1-9]{1})([0-9]+)?[.]?([0-9]+)?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
//          '|---------|----|--------------|--------|---|--------|----|---|
$cRegex .= '([-+*\/\(]?[\(]?[\(]?([1-9]{1})([0-9]+)?[.]?([0-9]+)?[\)]?[\)]?)?' ; 
$cRegex .= '$/' ;
```

Testei com as seguintes expressões numéricas :

- `+(690.91)+1` - Validou
- `+(690/2)+20.01+(10*3)-010` - Rejeitou corretamente
- `+(690/2)+20.01+(10*3)-10` - Validou
- `690` - Validou
- `690/09` - Rejeitou corretamente
- `690/9` - Validou

Obs: tirei os espaços em branco das expressões.

Comment: E a sua expressão pode ser qualquer uma ou será sempre neste formato? Conhece a notação polonesa (reversa)? Talvez seu problema seja resolvido mais facilmente com ela.

Comment: Como o conteúdo vem de uma base mysql, pode ser qualquer coisa, por isso que preciso saber se é um numero ou um expressão numérica para mudar o caminho.

Comment: Sobre a notação polonesa, realmente eu não conheço mas gostaria de saber aplicar em php7. Pode me dar um exemplo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como [você disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384310/como-validar-uma-express%C3%A3o-num%C3%A9rica-com-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular#comment759612_384310) que a expressão pode ser "qualquer coisa", estou supondo que possa ter mais de um par de parênteses aninhados, como por exemplo:

```
690.91+(1.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))
```

A sua regex não consegue detectar isso, por causa dos parênteses aninhados. Na verdade, têm outros problemas também. Por exemplo, você se preocupou tanto em validar os casos mais complexos (como `+(690.91)`) que acabou deixando passar os casos mais simples, como `1+1` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/QQBoMl/2/)).

Alguns detalhes da sua regex:

- `[\(]` é o mesmo que `\(` (que aliás, é o mesmo que `[(]`, pois [dentro de colchetes, muitos caracteres não precisam ser escapados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special) com `\`, [veja um exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/RBr0xt/1/)). De qualquer forma, se você quer capturar apenas um caractere, não precisa dos colchetes, então para verificar uma abertura de parênteses, bastaria usar `\(`.

  - o mesmo vale para `[.]`, que pode ser escrito apenas como `\.`
  - os colchetes são úteis quando há mais de um caractere possível (ex: `[ab]` significa "a letra `a` ou a letra `b`"), mas quando você só quer capturar um caractere, eles são desnecessários
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{1}` significa "exatamente uma ocorrência", mas por *default*, qualquer coisa que você use em uma regex já indica que você quer uma ocorrência daquilo. Então `[1-9]{1}` é o mesmo que `[1-9]`.
- na primeira parte da regex você usou `([1-9]{1}[0-9]+)[.]?[0-9]+` (um dígito de 1 a 9, seguido de um ou mais dígitos de 0 a 9, seguido de um ponto opcional, seguido de um ou mais dígitos de 0 a 9). Ou seja, este trecho só valida números que tenham pelo menos 3 dígitos (caso não tenha o ponto), ou pelo menos 2 dígitos antes do ponto ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/JffwJW/1/)). Por isso que a regex não valida `1+1`.

  - nos outros trechos você usa `?` em vez de `+`, o que [torna alguns trechos opcionais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (por isso o segundo número pode ter menos que 3 dígitos, como em `690+1`)
- você deixou opcionais tanto a abertura quanto o fechamento de parênteses. Isso quer dizer que sua regex aceita expressões que tem um parênteses aberto, mas que não tem o respectivo fechamento, ou que não tem a abertura mas tem o fechamento ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/QQBoMl/4/)).

---

#### Corrigindo/melhorando...

Para os números, você poderia usar algo como `-?(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.

Ela começa com o sinal de menos [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (`-?`). Depois temos um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - o trecho dentro de `(?=` - que verifica se o que está à frente é um dígito de 1 a 9 **ou** um zero que não esteja seguido de outro dígito (o caractere `|` [significa **ou**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) e o trecho `0(?!\d)` garante que não existe um dígito à frente do zero). Assim a expressão pode ter o número zero sozinho (`0`), mas não pode ter `09`, por exemplo).

Depois temos `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos), seguido opcionalmente por um ponto e mais dígitos (assim podemos ter `10` e `10.1`).

Se você quiser que a regex também aceite números como `.123` (que é outra forma de escrever `0.123`), basta mudar para `-?(?:(?=[1-9]|0(?!\d))\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)` - isso quer dizer que ela aceita números da maneira já explicada acima **ou** um ponto seguido de um ou mais dígitos. ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Sf8Xws/1/) alguns exemplos desta regex).

---

Depois, para a expressão aritmética em si, não basta fazer um monte de sub-expressões e deixá-las opcionais. É preciso verificar, entre outras coisas, se os parênteses estão balanceados (para cada abertura há o fechamento correspondente).

O outro problema é que a expressão pode ter vários níveis de aninhamento dos parênteses, então não bastaria fazer como você fez (várias opções diferentes seguidas), pois as possibilidades são muitas: expressões sem parênteses, com 1 par de parênteses em cada operando, com vários pares aninhados em cada operando, etc.

Sem contar que sua regex limita a expressão a apenas 6 operandos (ex: `+690.91+1-2-1-3-4`). Se adicionarmos mais um (como `+690.91+1-2-1-3-4-1`), ela não é mais validada ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/lxpgWG/2/)). *(Este caso até daria para resolver trocando os `?` no fim de cada trecho por `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), mas ainda sim não resolveria os outros problemas já citados).*

A solução, neste caso, é usar [padrões recursivos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) e [sub-rotinas](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#define) (*regex deliberadamente copiada [daqui](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=889408#replies_table) e adaptada para o caso em questão*):

```
$regex = '{
    (?(DEFINE)
       (?<number>    (?: -? (?: (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (?:\.\d+)? ) | \.\d+ ) )
       (?<sign>      (?: [-+] ))
       (?<expr>      (?: (?&term) (?: \s* [-+] \s* (?&expr))? ))
       (?<term>      (?: (?&factor) (?: \s* [/*] \s* (?&term))? ))
       (?<factor>    (?: (?&number) |
                         (?&sign) \s* (?&factor) |
                        \( \s* (?&expr) \s* \)))
    )
    ^ \s* (?&expr) \s* $
}x';
```

Essa regex é **bem** complexa. O primeiro trecho (dentro do bloco `(?(DEFINE)`) define sub-rotinas. Basicamente, são criadas "sub-expressões", cada uma um nome. A sintaxe `(?<nome>` define a sub-rotina, e a sintaxe `(?&nome)` substitui este trecho pela regex correspondente.

Por exemplo, a primeira sub-rotina se chama "number" (sua definição está dentro do trecho delimitado por `(?<number>`), e ela corresponde à regex que verifica um número (a mesma já citada acima). Em seguida, nas outras sub-rotinas vemos o uso de `(?&number)` - este trecho é substituído pela regex correspondente.

Depois temos a sub-rotina "sign", que captura o sinal (`[-+]`, um sinal de menos ou de mais). Em seguida definimos as sub-rotinas "factor", "term" e "expr":

- um "expr" pode ter um "term" sozinho, ou somado/subtraído a outra "expr"
- um "term" pode ser um "factor" sozinho, ou multiplicado/dividido por outro "term"
- um "factor" pode ser um "number", ou um "factor" com um "sign" antes, ou uma "expr" entre parênteses

Repare que a estrutura é recursiva (por isso a regex consegue verificar vários parênteses aninhados e expressões de qualquer tamanho). E em vários lugares eu uso `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços), assim a regex permite que hajam espaços na expressão.

Depois do bloco `DEFINE`, há a regex propriamente dita: `^ \s* (?&expr) \s* $`. Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Depois temos espaços opcionais no início e fim, e no meio deles temos a expressão.

Outro ponto importante é que eu uso o [modificador](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `x` (no final da string), pois isso faz com que a regex ignore as quebras de linha e os espaços em branco. Isso permite escrevê-la da maneira acima (com vários espaços e quebras de linha, deixando-a mais organizada e um pouco mais fácil de ler). Se eu não usasse o `x`, toda a regex acima teria que ser escrita em uma única linha, e sem espaços - o que a tornaria ainda mais difícil de ser lida e entendida.

Outro detalhe é que, em vez de delimitar a regex com `/`, eu usei chaves (`{}`). Com isso, as barras dentro da regex não precisam ser escritas como `\/` (tudo bem que só há uma barra na regex, mas particularmente, eu prefiro minimizar a quantidade de `\` sempre que possível).

Testando a regex:

```
$list = array('+(690.91)+1', '+(690/2)+20.01+(10*3)-010', '+(690/2)+20.01+(10*3)-10', '690',
  '690/09', '690/9', '1+1', '690 + 1', '10+(10*10)-20', '690.91+(1.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))',
  '690.91+(01.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))', '.24+3', '+(690.91+1', '+690.91+1-2-1-3-4-1',
  '690.91+(1.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))/(-1.3*4/(3.2-(1/7.5)))');
foreach ($list as $exp) {
    echo $exp. '='. (preg_match($regex, $exp) ? 'ok' : 'nok'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Ela está de acordo com os seus exemplos, com o bônus de validar os casos que a sua regex não consegue (parênteses aninhados, `1+1`, expressões com espaços, etc):

```
+(690.91)+1=ok
+(690/2)+20.01+(10*3)-010=nok
+(690/2)+20.01+(10*3)-10=ok
690=ok
690/09=nok
690/9=ok
1+1=ok
690 + 1=ok
10+(10*10)-20=ok
690.91+(1.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))=ok
690.91+(01.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))=nok
.24+3=ok
+(690.91+1=nok
+690.91+1-2-1-3-4-1=ok
690.91+(1.3*(4-7/(3+6.4)))/(-1.3*4/(3.2-(1/7.5)))=ok
```

---

Mas talvez regex não seja a melhor solução para o seu caso. Já tentou ver algum [*parser* específico para expressões aritméticas](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20parse%20arithmetic%20expression)? Apesar de ser legal, [regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). Vale lembrar também que a regex só valida a expressão, mas não calcula o seu valor (e nesse caso, uma solução melhor seria usar [funções/APIs específicas](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20evaluate%20arithmetic%20expression)).

Comment: Sem dúvida minha experiência com regex é simplória, estou apenas começando. Muito boa a sua solução fora a aula de regex, vou aplicar no meu projeto e procurar entender bem o que você passou para futuras implementações.

Comment: Antes de postar sobre este assunto pesquisei e até comprei um livro, mas devido a complexidade e vendo a sua própria solução, fico contente em deixar aqui o registro para que outras pessoas desfrutem do que foi passado. Vou ver sobre a dica de "parser específico para expressões aritméticas" e grato pelo apoio.

Comment: @MarcioSouza Dois sites de regex que eu gosto bastante são [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [esse](https://www.rexegg.com), tem tutoriais muito bons e com vários exemplos. E livros, eu recomendo [esse](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) (que é bem avançado e vai fundo no assunto) e [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432). Regex é um assunto sem fim, então bons estudos :-)