# Capitalizar texto em JavaScript, ignorando abreviações

Tags: javascript, regex, capitalização

Tenho um código em JavaScript para capitalizar texto que trata algumas exceções.

Contudo, gostaria de tratar mais algumas, tais como ignorar abreviações, que seriam ter um ponto antes ou depois da primeira letra e ignorar alguns algarismos romanos.

Alguma sugestão?
Segue meu código até o momento:

```js
function testaCapitalize() {
  var texto1 = "alto dO cruzeiro";
  var texto2 = "joão paulo II";
  var texto3 = "N.S. aparecida";
  var texto4 = "N.S. DAS GRAÇAS";
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML =
    capitalize(texto1) +
    "<br/>" +
    capitalize(texto2) +
    "<br/>" +
    capitalize(texto3) +
    "<br/>" +
    capitalize(texto4);
}

function capitalize(texto) {

  texto = texto.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(capitalize) {
    return capitalize.toUpperCase();
  });
  //preposição digitada
  var PreposM = ["Da", "Do", "Das", "Dos", "A", "E", "De", "DE"];
  //preposição substituta
  var prepos = ["da", "do", "das", "dos", "a", "e", "de", "de"];

  for (var i = PreposM.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    texto = texto.replace(RegExp("\\b" + PreposM[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "\\b", "g"), prepos[i]);
  }

  return texto;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="testaCapitalize()" value='Testa'>
<div id='resultado'>

</div>
```

```
function capitalize(texto) {

    texto = texto.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(capitalize) {
      return capitalize.toUpperCase();
    });
    //preposição digitada
    var PreposM = ["Da", "Do", "Das", "Dos", "A", "E", "De", "DE"];
    //preposição substituta
    var prepos = ["da", "do", "das", "dos", "a", "e", "de", "de"];

    for (var i = PreposM.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      texto = texto.replace(RegExp("\\b" + PreposM[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "\\b", "g"), prepos[i]);
    }

  return texto;
}
```

Comment: Pelos itens do array, suponho que você é de Juazeiro/BA, Marlucio! Tua pergunta, as respostas e comentários aqui presentes me ajudaram bastante! Valeu!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Talvez seja mais simples fazer um [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para quebrar o texto em palavras, aí você verifica cada palavra separadamente. Depois é só juntar tudo de novo no final.

Isso é mais fácil do que tentar uma regex gigante que trata todos os casos de uma vez ([embora até seja possível](https://regex101.com/r/kUQHtT/2), não acho que vale a pena a complicação).

Assumindo que sempre há um espaço separando as palavras, uma maneira de resolver seria:

```js
function abreviacao(s) {
    return /^([A-Z]\.)+$/.test(s);
}

function numeralRomano(s) {
    return /^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/.test(s);
}

function capitalize(texto) {
    let prepos = ["da", "do", "das", "dos", "a", "e", "de" ];
    return texto.split(' ') // quebra o texto em palavras
       .map((palavra) => { // para cada palavra
           if (abreviacao(palavra) || numeralRomano(palavra)) {
                return palavra;
           }

           palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
           if (prepos.includes(palavra)) {
                return palavra;
           }
           return palavra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palavra.slice(1);
       })
       .join(' '); // junta as palavras novamente
}

let textos = ["alto dO cruzeiro", "joão paulo II", "N.S. aparecida", "N.S. DAS GRAÇAS"];
textos.forEach(t => console.log(capitalize(t)));
```

O `split` retorna um array contendo as palavras. Em seguida eu uso [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para trocar cada palavra pelo seu equivalente "capitalizado".

Caso a palavra seja abreviação ou numeral romano, ela é retornada sem modificação. Se ela é uma das preposições, é transformada em minúscula.

Caso não seja nenhuma das exceções, apenas a primeira letra é convertida para maiúscula. Por fim, eu uso [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para juntar todas as palavras em uma única string, tendo as palavras separadas por espaço.

O resultado do código acima é:

```
Alto do Cruzeiro
João Paulo II
N.S. Aparecida
N.S. das Graças
```

---

Para a abreviação eu usei a regex `/^([A-Z]\.)+$/`: uma letra maiúscula seguida de ponto, [podendo se repetir várias vezes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (ex: "A.", "A.B.", "A.B.C.", etc, todas são consideradas abreviações). Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (respectivamente o início e fim da string) garantem que a palavra só pode ter isso.

Mas se quiser verificar apenas que a primeira letra está seguida de um ponto e tanto faz o resto, pode trocar para `/^[A-Z]\./` (ou `/^[A-Z]\./i` para considerar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas).

Para numerais romanos, peguei a regex [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405). A princípio você poderia verificar se a string só possui os caracteres I, V, X, L, D, C e M, mas a regex também verifica as quantidades e ordem em que aparecem, evitando casos inválidos como `XM`, por exemplo ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/8rcDXR/1/) mais alguns exemplos).

Comment: Uau! Quem que fez essa regex gigante? Nunca tinha visto uma desse tamanho. Aliás, boa resposta, como sempre. :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe Se está falando [dessa](https://regex101.com/r/kUQHtT/2), fui eu mesmo :-) Confesso que só fiz pra saber se era possível, pois acho que não usaria isso em produção. Além disso ela não funciona em JavaScript, teria que mudar algumas coisas e continuaria um monstro. Pra terminar, tem regex piores que essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/384502/112052, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829

Comment: O array de preposições ficou com um `"de"` repetido.

Comment: @Isac Corrigido, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Para facilitar o trabalho você pode utilizar a biblioteca https://www.npmjs.com/package/capitalize-pt-br

Instalando da seguinte forma, caso utilizado o NPM:

```
npm install --save capitalize-pt-br
```

Em caso de não utilização do NPM, pode-se baixar a biblioteca e implementar no projeto fazendo o import manual do script

A implementação com a biblioteca seria a seguinte:

```
const capitalize = require('capitalize-pt-br')

capitalize('HELLO WORLD')
```

Esta função retornaria o seguinte:

> Hello World

Caso haja necessidade de manter uma palavra minúscula, pode-se usar o segundo parâmetro da função, da seguinte forma:

```
const capitalize = require('capitalize-pt-br')

capitalize('HELLO WORLD', ['world'])
```

Esta função retornaria o seguinte:

> Hello world

Caso haja necessidade de manter uma palavra minúscula e outra maiúscula, pode-se usar o segundo parâmetro da função, da seguinte forma:

```
const capitalize = require('capitalize-pt-br')

capitalize('HELLO WORLD', ['world'], ['hello'])
```

Esta função retornaria o seguinte:

> HELLO world

Comment: entendi, mas não resolve a questão dos pontos em abreviações.

Comment: @MarlucioPires Você pode criar um arquivo com a seguinte estrutura https://github.com/ranpa/capitalize-pt-br/blob/master/src/keep-uppercase.js e passar as siglas que você quer manter maíusculo. Caso haja necessidade de automatizar essa capitalização das siglas, será necessário a utilização de REGEX