# Melhoria de função para Capitalize

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Esta função me retorna a primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúscula

```
String(str).replace(/(^|\s)\S/g, (v) => { return v.toUpperCase() })
```

Ou seja, este nome **roberto monteiro** se **torna Roberto Monteiro** porém este nome **roberto de monteiro** também se torna **Roberto De Monteiro** e **roberto o monteiro** se torna **Roberto O Monteiro**, tentei

```
String(str).replace(/(^|\s)\S{3,}/g, (v) => { return v.toUpperCase() })
```

e também

```
String(str).replace(/(^|\s){,3}\S/g, (v) => { return v.toUpperCase() })
```

porém, elas retornam **ROBERTO de MONTEIRO** ou **ROBERTO o MONTEIRO** e **Roberto monteiro** ou **Roberto o monteiro**

teria como dentro desta função, detectar palavra menor que 3 caracteres e não fazer nada?
de preferencia dentro dela, sem precisar ir para outra função?
ou uma outra função de preferencia de 1 linha.

Comment: A duplicada sugerida acima não é 100% igual a sua, mas dá pra adaptar tranquilamente [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/399475/112052) para o seu caso

Comment: Não sei se chegou a ver mas tinha uma resposta usando regex. Nos comentários dessa resposta foi chegado a conclusão de que regex não é o caminho. O código seria esse `String(str).replace(/\b\S(?=\S{2,})/g, (v) => {
  return v.toUpperCase()` .Como dito pelo moderador Bacco, nomes como Jorge Dos Santos, Sílvia sá, jó Ezequiel, hu Sung Chun, Maria Das Dores, Jet li, og Mandino não serão capitalizados corretamente. Assim não sendo possível calibrar o look-ahead para cada caso .

Comment: Só um detalhe: `{,3}` na verdade corresponde aos próprios caracteres `{`, `,`, `3` e `}`. Se quer de zero a 3 ocorrências, use `{0,3}` - veja a diferença: https://repl.it/repls/WarmLimitedState - De qualquer forma, mesmo se fizesse `(^|\s){0,3}`, vc estaria buscando de zero a 3 espaços (e não de zero a 3 letras, como vc gostaria), e mesmo se conseguisse pegar as 3 letras, ainda tem o problema citado no comentário acima, de ter vários nomes curtos que seriam erroneamente ignorados.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Uma alternativa seria usar *lookahead* negativo para ignorar somente as preposições "de", "do", etc: `s.replace(/\b(?!d?[aeo]s?\b)(\w)(\w+)\b/gi, function(v, primeiraLetra, resto) { return primeiraLetra.toUpperCase() + resto.toLowerCase(); })` - só que ele não pega os casos em que está tudo em maiúsculo (ex: "FULANO DE TAL" vira "Fulano DE Tal"): https://repl.it/repls/WickedFloweryServerapplication - No fim, acho que a solução da duplicada me parece melhor mesmo...

Comment: @hkotsubo, é uma boa solução. É o caso apenas de previamente processar a entrada com toLowerCase().

Comment: Valew a todos, eu realmente não consegui procurar direito por ter pensado no assunto e não estar com tempo na hora mas ajudaram demais mesmo me mostrando a duplicata