# Como aplicar capitalização no texto de parágrafos com classes específicas diretamente no corpo da página?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Baseando-me [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399451/capitalizar-texto-em-javascript-ignorando-abrevia%C3%A7%C3%B5es), adaptei uma resposta específica para meu caso, criando um array com os parágrafos de interesse, onde minha intenção é capitalizar o texto presente nesses respectivos parágrafos (com algumas exceções, a exemplo de abreviaturas, preposições e números romanos).

O código funciona perfeitamente, entretanto não consigo fazer com que os resultados capitalizados substituam os anteriores (antes da capitalização) no corpo do HTML. Já removi a linha `console.log`, substituindo-a por um `capitalize(innerHTMLs);` - que funciona quando vejo o resultado no console, mas não estou conseguindo fazer essa referida substituição na página em si.

Uma coisa que descobri é que usar `document.getElementsByClassName('h6').innerHTML = 'Novo valor'` não funciona, a menos que eu use um ID em vez de classe.

Alguma ideia de como posso substituir o texto dos parágrafos com as classes `h6` e `professor` pelos respectivos valores capitalizados na função `capitalize()`? Em outras palavras:

```
<p class="h6">PREPOSIÇÃO DA SILVA</p>
```

se transformar em

```
<p class="h6">Preposição da Silva</p>
```

Este é o código que estou usando:

```js
var innerHTMLs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[class='h6'], [class='professor']")).map(function(x){return x.innerHTML});

function abreviacao(s) {
    return /^([A-Z]\.)+$/.test(s);
}

function numeralRomano(s) {
    return /^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/.test(s);
}

function capitalize(texto) {
    let prepos = ["da", "do", "das", "dos", "e", "de", "à", "ao", "às", "aos", "tfc" ];
    return texto.split(' ') // quebra o texto em palavras
       .map((palavra) => { // para cada palavra
           if (abreviacao(palavra) || numeralRomano(palavra)) {
                return palavra;
           }

           palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
           if (prepos.includes(palavra)) {
                return palavra;
           }
           return palavra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palavra.slice(1);
       })
       .join(' '); // junta as palavras novamente
}

innerHTMLs.forEach(t => console.log(capitalize(t)));
```

```html
<p class="h6">PREPOSIÇÃO DA SILVA</p>
<p class="professor">ROMANOS IX</p>
<p class="h6">PREPOSIÇÃO DOS SANTOS</p>
<p class="professor">JOÃO PAULO II</p>
<p class="h6">INTRODUÇÃO À PRIMEIRA CARTA AOS CORÍNTIOS</p>
<p class="professor">REFERENTE AO PARÁGRAFO IV</p>
```

Comment: Sua função `capitalize` apenas retorna o texto, não altera em ponto algum, para trocar é necessário a referência ao elemento, mas sua variável `innerHTMLs` só contém os "textos" (na verdade os HTMLs), não as referências para os elementos, precisa alterar pra salvar elas. `getElementsByClassName` retorna um array de elementos, e não um elemnto, por isso o `.innerHTML` não funcionará, teria que iterar ele para fazer algo como `elements[0].innerHTML = capitalize(innerHTMLs[0])`, `elements[1].innerHTML = capitalize(innerHTMLs[1])`, ...

Comment: @Costamilam Primeiramente, obrigado pelo comentário! Eu já havia tentado fazer isso que você me sugeriu, usando `innerHTMLs[0].innerHTML = capitalize(innerHTMLs[0])`, mas sem sucesso. De fato, ocorre a capitalização no elemento que eu referencio, mas não ocorre a substituição dentro da página.

Comment: Inclusive, eu havia criado um laço `for(var i = 0; i < innerHTMLs.length; i++){innerHTMLs[i].innerHTML = capitalize(innerHTMLs[i])}`, mas, como disse, sem sucesso na substituição.

Comment: Isso porque `innerHTMLs[i]` não é uma referência ao elemento HTML, mas sim HTML dentro do elemento como uma string. Como eu disse, precisa adaptar a sua variável `innerHTMLs` para guardar o elemento, e não o seu conteúdo (`.innerHTML`)

Comment: @Costamilam Entendi. Vou pesquisar como fazer isso (guardar o elemento - texto - em vez do conteúdo). Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer trocar o `innerHTML` de cada um dos elementos, bastaria usar o resultado de [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (que [retorna uma lista dos elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Return_value)), percorrê-los e trocar o `innerHTML` destes pela versão capitalizada:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class='h6'], [class='professor']")
    .forEach(e => e.innerHTML = capitalize(e.innerHTML));
```

Exemplo completo:

```js
function abreviacao(s) {
    return /^([A-Z]\.)+$/.test(s);
}

function numeralRomano(s) {
    return /^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/.test(s);
}

function capitalize(texto) {
    let prepos = ["da", "do", "das", "dos", "e", "de", "à", "ao", "às", "aos", "tfc" ];
    return texto.split(' ') // quebra o texto em palavras
       .map((palavra) => { // para cada palavra
           if (abreviacao(palavra) || numeralRomano(palavra)) {
                return palavra;
           }

           palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
           if (prepos.includes(palavra)) {
                return palavra;
           }
           return palavra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palavra.slice(1);
       })
       .join(' '); // junta as palavras novamente
}

function capitalizarTudo() {
    document.querySelectorAll("[class='h6'], [class='professor']")
        .forEach(e => e.innerHTML = capitalize(e.innerHTML));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="capitalizarTudo()">Clique para capitalizar os parágrafos</button>
<p class="h6">PREPOSIÇÃO DA SILVA</p>
<p class="professor">ROMANOS IX</p>
<p class="h6">PREPOSIÇÃO DOS SANTOS</p>
<p class="professor">JOÃO PAULO II</p>
<p class="h6">INTRODUÇÃO À PRIMEIRA CARTA AOS CORÍNTIOS</p>
<p class="professor">REFERENTE AO PARÁGRAFO IV</p>
```

Da forma que você fez, estava apenas pegando os textos (o próprio `innerHTML`), passando para a função `capitalize` e imprimindo o resultado no console. Por isso os textos não eram alterados nos respectivos elementos.

---

Obs: aqui estamos levando em conta que dentro dos elementos não há outras tags (e neste caso, poderia ser inclusive usado [`innerText` em vez de `innerHTML`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/329975/112052) que não faria diferença). Mas caso tenha outras tags dentro dos elementos, aí você teria que tomar cuidado para não substituir as próprias tags, seus atributos etc).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, @hkotsubo! Em relação à tua observação, não há outras tags dentro dos parágrafos. Muito obrigado pela instrução e pelas dicas! Valeu!